# Duplicate removal in time series based on other column using R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I am currently working on a problem which involves data cleaning and calculation in below fashion :
I have created the sample dataset here for a single unit A.
Data is sorted according to timestamp column for each unit. There are other columns as well.
For each distinct alternate value of `event_log_value_desc`, I need to get rows. In the case of multiple duplicate values of `event_log_value_desc`, it should return the row with the first occurrence of `event_log_value_desc`. `event_log_value_desc` should have alternate values of OFF and ON for each unit.

[image]

In return, the program should return the following :

[image]

Comment: Can you please give some sample data using the function `dput` and pasting the output in your question? In this way people will be facilitated in helping you. Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this solution works since it has not been tested on your dataset, but I believe it should be fine

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(unit) %>% 
  mutate(event_log_value_desc_lag = lag(event_log_value_desc)) %>% 
  filter(event_log_value_desc != event_log_value_desc_lag | is.na(event_log_value_desc_lag))
```

Comment: Thank you Ric. It worked and tested it on few units.

Comment: @User1101 Nice to hear that! If you want to clarify what the code does I will edit my answer with a bit of explanation. Also, if you found my answer useful, please consider upvoting it :)